# My api stored on Kubernates engine returns different responses whith same request

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, get

I have very strange problem with app stored on Kubernates. 
On localhost everything is working perfectly, but when I send GET request to for example:
http://35.188.95.65/store/costs
I get different responses, with diferent arrays...
Tested on Postman. I tried to deploy app few times, delete, restart instances, and can't get solution.
I think it changes over about 1 minute interval. The same with other endpoints.
Can someone give me a clue what's going on?

Comment: You need to provide more detail. Where does the data come from? is it the same database? Are the environment variables different?

Comment: I am newbe in this field. Data comes from my app hosted on Google VPS. There is one database only and it is writed as constans on NodeJS app. I didn't change or set any enviromental variables, don't know how it is working honestly.

Comment: You need to check which database it connects to when you're running on localhost, then check if the same db is used on k8. Also check any config values/environment variables, if you are getting different data then probably there is a difference in the configuration.